# My computer could not locate pip all of a sudden, and when I reinstalled it, all of my Python packages were gone?

Tags: python, pip, package

I was working on a Python/Flask project, and I am not sure what happened but all of a sudden when I opened my Terminal, it seemed like `pip` was deleted; when I tried running things like '`pip list`' from different directories (including my global one), I got the following

```
zsh: command not found: pip
```

Needless to say, when I tried running packages that I had previously installed with pip like `Flask`, I got the same zsh error as per above.

And when I reinstalled pip and ran `pip list`, it seems like all of my Python packages got deleted?:

```
pip        22.1.2
setuptools 58.1.0
wheel      0.37.1
```

Any ideas what could have caused this? I can reinstall the packages that is no issue. But I fear this will happen again in the future and I have no idea what I did that could have caused this...

Could this have been a $PATH issue?

When I run `echo $PATH` in my global directory, I get:

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/bin
/opt/homebrew/bin
/opt/homebrew/sbin
/usr/local/bin
/usr/bin
/bin
/usr/sbin
/sbin
/Library/Apple/usr/bin
```

**@mast o;**

Here is what I get when running `find / -name pip`:
/Users/patrickchong/PycharmProjects/Live_Server/venv/bin/pip
/Users/patrickchong/PycharmProjects/Live_Server/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip
/Users/patrickchong/PycharmProjects/JP interview/venv/bin/pip
/Users/patrickchong/PycharmProjects/JP interview/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip
/Users/patrickchong/opt/anaconda3/bin/pip
/Users/patrickchong/opt/anaconda3/pkgs/pip-21.2.4-py310hecd8cb5_0/bin/pip
/Users/patrickchong/opt/anaconda3/pkgs/pip-21.2.4-py310hecd8cb5_0/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip
/Users/patrickchong/opt/anaconda3/pkgs/pip-21.2.4-py39hecd8cb5_0/bin/pip
/Users/patrickchong/opt/anaconda3/pkgs/pip-21.2.4-py39hecd8cb5_0/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip
/Users/patrickchong/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip
find: /Users/patrickchong/.Trash: Operation not permitted
/Users/patrickchong/.conda/envs/Crypto Trading Bot project/bin/pip
/Users/patrickchong/.conda/envs/Crypto Trading Bot project/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip
/Users/patrickchong/.conda/envs/AlgoExpert Questions/bin/pip
/Users/patrickchong/.conda/envs/AlgoExpert Questions/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip
/Applications/iFunia YouTube Downloader.app/Contents/Frameworks/ASVDSDK.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip
/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.13_1/libexec/bin/pip
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.13_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/share/doc/python3.9/examples/Tools/msi/pip
find: /dev/fd/3: Not a directory
find: /dev/fd/4: Not a directory
find: /dev/fd/6: Not a directory

(I omitted a lot of the "find ....", because it was a very long list)

Here is what I get when I run `pip3`:

```
patrickchong@Patricks-MacBook-Pro ~ % pip3

Usage:   
  pip3 <command> [options]

Commands:
  install                     Install packages.
  download                    Download packages.
  uninstall                   Uninstall packages.
  freeze                      Output installed packages in requirements format.
  list                        List installed packages.
  show                        Show information about installed packages.
  check                       Verify installed packages have compatible dependencies.
  config                      Manage local and global configuration.
  search                      Search PyPI for packages.
  cache                       Inspect and manage pip's wheel cache.
  index                       Inspect information available from package indexes.
  wheel                       Build wheels from your requirements.
  hash                        Compute hashes of package archives.
  completion                  A helper command used for command completion.
  debug                       Show information useful for debugging.
  help                        Show help for commands.

General Options:
  -h, --help                  Show help.
  --debug                     Let unhandled exceptions propagate outside the
                              main subroutine, instead of logging them to
                              stderr.
  --isolated                  Run pip in an isolated mode, ignoring
                              environment variables and user configuration.
  --require-virtualenv        Allow pip to only run in a virtual environment;
                              exit with an error otherwise.
  -v, --verbose               Give more output. Option is additive, and can be
                              used up to 3 times.
  -V, --version               Show version and exit.
  -q, --quiet                 Give less output. Option is additive, and can be
                              used up to 3 times (corresponding to WARNING,
                              ERROR, and CRITICAL logging levels).
  --log <path>                Path to a verbose appending log.
  --no-input                  Disable prompting for input.
  --proxy <proxy>             Specify a proxy in the form
                              scheme://[user:passwd@]proxy.server:port.
  --retries <retries>         Maximum number of retries each connection should
                              attempt (default 5 times).
  --timeout <sec>             Set the socket timeout (default 15 seconds).
  --exists-action <action>    Default action when a path already exists:
                              (s)witch, (i)gnore, (w)ipe, (b)ackup, (a)bort.
  --trusted-host <hostname>   Mark this host or host:port pair as trusted,
                              even though it does not have valid or any HTTPS.
  --cert <path>               Path to PEM-encoded CA certificate bundle. If
                              provided, overrides the default. See 'SSL
                              Certificate Verification' in pip documentation
                              for more information.
  --client-cert <path>        Path to SSL client certificate, a single file
                              containing the private key and the certificate
                              in PEM format.
  --cache-dir <dir>           Store the cache data in <dir>.
  --no-cache-dir              Disable the cache.
  --disable-pip-version-check
                              Don't periodically check PyPI to determine
                              whether a new version of pip is available for
                              download. Implied with --no-index.
  --no-color                  Suppress colored output.
  --no-python-version-warning
                              Silence deprecation warnings for upcoming
                              unsupported Pythons.
  --use-feature <feature>     Enable new functionality, that may be backward
                              incompatible.
  --use-deprecated <feature>  Enable deprecated functionality, that will be
                              removed in the future.
```

Comment: Is there a chance you worked with pipenv or venv all this time? what is the result of running `find / -name pip`?
maybe you work with python3 and used pip3 all this time with alias to pip. 
What is the output of `pip3`?

Comment: Hi master o, you are right that I have been using a venv for the project all this time- could this have caused pip to be deleted? Because I definitely had pip installed everywhere (including the global directory), but now it seems it does not exist anywhere! Let me include the rest of your suggestions in my question

Comment: I have been executing both python and python3, but in terms of pip I have only used pip and never pip3 !

Comment: seems like there are pip exec files in a lot of places, you probably used one or some of them all this time, and your packages are probably there, to see which of your python environments(pip locations) have flask(maybe all of the other packages too) just run `find / -name flask` and add its path (without flask) to the PATH env var, notice you should add it by appending a line to your ~/.zshrc or ~/.bashrc containing `export PATH=$PATH:<flask-path>`.